# Selected option for current url in drop down list not working

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, archive, selected

Using this bit of code in my wordpress theme:

```
<select name="archive-dropdown" onChange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="">Select month</option>
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&format=option'); ?>
</select>
```

Taken from here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives

This is the outputted code

```
<select name="archive-dropdown" onChange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="">Select month</option>
<option value='http://www.domain.com/?m=201307'> July 2013 </option>
<option value='http://www.domain.com/?m=201306'> June 2013 </option>
<option value='http://www.domain.com/?m=201305'> May 2013 </option>
</select>
```

For example, if I select July, the July archive page comes up and I checked that the address of the page is correct: http://www.domain.com/?m=201307

But the July option is not selected in the drop down. I understand that the bit of javascript in the onChange field is comparing the document href to the options and then selecting the matching option value, but it doesn't appear to be working.

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out creating a custom filter in my WordPress theme functions. Placed this in my theme's `functions.php`:

```
function get_archives_link_mod ( $link_html ) {
    preg_match ("/value='(.+?)'/", $link_html, $url);
    $requested = "http://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
    if ($requested == $url[1]) {
        $link_html = str_replace("<option", "<option selected='selected'", $link_html);
    }
    return $link_html;
}
```

Then placed this in my theme's `archive.php`:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <select name="archive-dropdown" onChange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="">PICK MONTH</option>
        <?php add_filter("get_archives_link", "get_archives_link_mod"); ?>
        <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&format=option'); ?>
    </select> 
</form>
```

I basically took the code suggested [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_get_archives-highlight-current-archive-please) for highlighting the current link in the default list version of `wp_get_archives()` and modified it for the option format of the function. It took a bit of digging as a non-coder and posting it here is probably as consequential as a tree falling with no one around to hear it, but I'll just give myself a pat on the back and pretend it was someone else's hand in this sad and desolate world.

Comment: The `$requested` variable would be wrong if using any ports or SSL, this version is more accurate `$requested = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`